# Android port always 0

Tags: android

I have a problem while using Network Service Discovery.

When i use my get port function.

```
  Log.d("Quiz", "Services " +service.getServiceName());
  Log.d("Quiz", "Port " +String.valueOf(service.getPort()));
```

I expect it to return a port, however every time i use get port for a service it always returns 0 for every service i find even the one i register which shouldn't be 0.

The getServiceName works fine just the getPort seems not to.

Is this suppose to happen, is every port supposed to be 0 or am i missing something?

Thanks

Edit: 
Code used

```
        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.d("Quiz", "Services " +service.getServiceName());
            Log.d("Quiz", "Port " +String.valueOf(service.getPort()));
            boolean found=false;
            if (service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
                if(servers.size()==0){
                    servers.add(service.getServiceName());
                    Log.d("Quiz", "Services Added");
                }
                for(int i=0;i<servers.size();i++){
                    if(servers.get(i).equals(service.getServiceName()))
                    {
                        found=true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(found==false) {
                servers.add(service.getServiceName());
                Log.d("Quiz", "Services Added");
            }
        }
```

Registration

```
   public void registerService(int port) {
    tearDown();
    initializeRegistrationListener();
    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo  = new NsdServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.setPort(port);
    serviceInfo.setServiceName(mServiceName);
    serviceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);

    manager.registerService(
            serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);

}
```

Registration confirmation

```
   @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo NsdServiceInfo) {
            mServiceName = NsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
            Log.d("Quiz", "Regsistered name " + NsdServiceInfo.getServiceName());
            Log.d("Quiz", "Regsistered port " + String.valueOf(NsdServiceInfo.getPort()));
        }
```

When i pass in any number to registerService for the port it returns 0 in the confirmation.

Edit:

The service type on the service is registered as null even though i set it to  _http._tcp. if that helps.

```
Log.d("Quiz", "Service Type " + NsdServiceInfo.getServiceType());
```

Comment: What is `service`?

Comment: I am using Network Service Discovery, so service is the services i find.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. In particular, show how you are getting your `service` object.